# NHibernate Validator - how to validate enum type

Tags: nhibernate, validation

I'm using nhibernate validator in my current solution. Everythings is almost fine but...

My view model has a property of type Gender (see example below)

public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

public enum Gender
{
        Female = 1, Male = 2
}

Now i like to have some validation to ensure that the gender property ist set. But neither the NotEmpty nor the NotNull Attribute fulfil the requirement.

Is there a kind of a generic solution or best practice to handle enum validations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom validator.

[Here is a decent blog post about how to go about writing a custom validator](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/07/30/writing-a-custom-nhibernate-class-validator.aspx).